# How to globally disable notifications?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, notification

I consider Ux notifications (pop-ups, etc.) to far more often be a dark design, than actually beneficial or even simply neutral.

The version of Gnome Desktop packaged with Ubuntu 20.04 is aggressive about letting every application invoke notifications, and is—ostensibly—organized along an *opt out* model where I have to manually configure settings so that, say, the calculator is not privileged to annoy me with notification features:

How can I:

- Globally disable ***all*** notifications with one command, or one Ux interaction.
- Make such disabling ***permanent*** (i.e., if I manually click through the dozens of application's multi-toggle notification preferences in Settings, a short time later—On reboot? On logging out and back in?—they are *all* back to full notification status).
- Permit/opt in Evolution/Calendar event notices, and ***only*** Evolution/Calendar event notices to remain active?